# Install WordPress with one domain on other webhoster with fix IP and a record set

Tags: php, wordpress, dns

I have a huge issue that I can't solve:

1. I have a website on HosterA with a subdomain blog.hosterA.com
2. A WordPress blog has to be set up on HosterB (which has a fix IP adress)
3. If I call blog.hosterA.com the browser has to show the WordPress blog on HosterB but the address line has to be blog.hosterA.com/article1 etc.

I have already set an a record from blog.hosterA.com to the IP adress. I can open the blog but it's far to slow and some PHP files are not working.

Could you please give me advice?

Comment: its called URL Masking, google thst and you will find the options. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Masking

Comment: So you think I could do this masking? I would use a mod rewrite, what about you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered actually putting the website on HosterB, and just iframe wrapping it on blog.hosterA.com?  That would be the most obvious and least intensive solution, IMO.

Comment: Could you clarify the reasoning behind wanting to do this? It could help me form a solution for you.

Comment: I have considered your proposed solution but the client knows about iframes and their misbehaviour in terms of SEO.
Could you imagine any other solution?